# How to open, modify and save a file with javascript and ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, iframe, activex, filesystemobject, input-type-file

I tried different methods to open and show a file on client without to send the file to a server.

Opening: I tried to access the file with javascript from a `<input type=file>`, but the security restriction seems to not allow that.
I tried also `<iframe src=file://local.path>` with the same problem.
Last i tried with `new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');`, but I get always an error that automationserver could not create the Object.

For saving I tried to use `execCommand('SaveAs',true)` from TextRange and DocumentFragment. From DocumentFragment I'm able to save a file but it contains only `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`. From TextRange is no save dialog shown.

What could I do?

Comment: These are all security restrictions. It would be helpful if you could explain how what you want to do differs fundamentally from what an attacker would like to do to hack the user's system.

Comment: For me are FileDialogs no problem, I want the user to select a file. I don't need to hide. I don't see security improvings in not allow client side editing. At the end there's no difference in the resulting file as if it would be sever side edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a web site, you cannot do any of this unless you use a [signed script](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html)

From local file system, IE can use the filesystem object from an [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Signing looks possible. HTA isn't the right for me. I think I will need to use UniversalXPConnect. But it looks difficult to sign the code.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support "signed script", nor "UniversalXPConnect."

Comment: I don't need cross browser support.

Comment: @Eric: One for Fx other for IE

Comment: I'm now so far getting a signed page with scripts displayed, but the permission stay denied.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

You can not access the local file system through a browser without having the user install a plug-in/activex object.

It may be that you should try another cross-platform delivery method, such as Adobe Air.

Comment: Adobe would be my last choice.